# test1.java:10: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown char ch = (char)br.read(); ^

Tags: java

Any help will be appreciated

My code:

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;
```

class Accept
{

```
public static void main(String args[])
{ 
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    char ch = br.read();
    System.out.print("Entered is: " + ch);
}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at [Lesson: Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error says, you have to either catch or throw the `IOException` thrown by mentioned method.

You can throw it by:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{ 
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    char ch = (char) br.read();
    System.out.print("Entered is: " + ch);
}
```

[Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) is a good place to start learning about Java Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          System.out.print("Enter: ");
          char ch = (char) br.read();
          System.out.print("Entered is: " + ch);
      }catch(IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(State.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```